# How to interrupt a form submit and modify CSS class attributes

Tags: php, form-submit, interrupt

I currently have a form that is posting a file, however I want to interrupt the submit so I can display a 'loading' gif and then submit. That way the gif acts as a loading symbol for larger files. I need a way to change the css class attribute from display:none to display:all. Any help?

My code:

```
 <html>
<head>
<title>Upload your media!</title>
<style type="text/css">
load {
display: none;

}

</style>
<script>
function validateForm()
{

var x=document.forms["mediaupload"]["title"].value;
if (x==null || x=="")
  {
  alert("Title must be filled out");
  return false;
  }

  var y=document.forms["mediaupload"]["info"].value;
if (y==null || y=="")
  {
  alert("Description must be filled out");
  return false;
  }
  var z=document.forms["mediaupload"]["file"].value;
  if (z==null || z=="")
  {
  alert("You need to select a file to upload");
  return false;
  }



}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>TOOB</h1>

<form name="mediaupload" action="upload_file.php" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post"
enctype="multipart/form-data">
<fieldset>
<legend><h4>Upload</h4></legend>
Title:<input type="text" name="title"><br>
Description:<textarea rows="10" cols="30" name="info">Write your desiption here</textarea><br>
Anonymous:<input type="checkbox" name="anonymous"><br>
File Upload:<input type="file" name="file" id="file"><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</fieldset>
</form>

<load><img id="loading" src="sitemedia/loading.gif" ></load>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Just like `onload` there is an `onunload` event that you can capture within your page.

Comment: Hi thanks for commenting, but sorry I haven't com across those functions before...

Answer (score 0):

use jQuery for this, remove the default submit and add timeout

```
$('form').submit(function(e)) {
    e.preventDefault();
    setTimeout(function() {
        this.submit();
    }, 5000);   // in milliseconds
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#form_id").submit(function(e){
       e.preventDefault();

       //Code for displaying the image 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do this in pure javascript.

**HTML**

I changed the submit button to this:

```
<input type="button" onclick="loadFunc()" name="submit" value="Submit">
```

And added this loading `div`:

```
<div id="loading" style="display:none">
<img src="sitemedia/loading.gif" />
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
function loadFunc() {
    document.getElementById("loading").style.display = "block";
    document.mediaupload.submit();
}
```

See [CodePen here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/aqiAh).